# React-Native Key Error - All Elements are deleted even though there is a unique key added to the KeyExtractor

Tags: javascript, react-native, key

I am adding a unique key to the FlatList and in theory only the button i press is supposed to be deleted but instead all elements are deleted

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import { Context } from "../context/BlogContext";
import { Entypo } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const IndexScreen = function () {
  const { state, addBlogPost, deleteBlogPost } = useContext(Context);
  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Add Post" onPress={() => addBlogPost()} />
      <FlatList
        data={state}
        keyExtractor={(blogPosts) => blogPosts.title}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.row}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>
                {item.title} - {item.id}
              </Text>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  deleteBlogPost(item.id);
                }}
              >
                <Entypo style={styles.icon} name="trash" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 20,
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "gray",
  },

  title: {
    fontSize: 18,
  },

  icon: {
    fontSize: 24,
  },
});

export default IndexScreen;
```

Context Screen:

```
import createDataContext from "./createDataContext";

const blogReducer = function (state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "delete_blogpost":
      return state.filter((blogPosts) => {
        blogPosts.id !== action.payload;
      });
    case "add_blogpost":
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999),
          title: `Blog Post #${state.length + 1}`,
        },
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const addBlogPost = function (dispatch) {
  return () => {
    dispatch({ type: "add_blogpost" });
  };
};

const deleteBlogPost = (dispatch) => {
  return (id) => {
    dispatch({ type: "delete_blogpost", payload: id });
  };
};

export const { Context, Provider } = createDataContext(
  blogReducer,
  { addBlogPost, deleteBlogPost },
  []
);
```

and

```
export default function (reducer, actions, initialState) {
 const Context = React.createContext();

 const Provider = ({ children }) => {
   const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

   // actions === { addBlogPost : (dispatch) => {return () => {}}}

   const boundActions = {};
   for (let key in actions) {
     boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
   }

   return (
     <Context.Provider value={{ state, ...boundActions }}>
       {children}
     </Context.Provider>
   );
 };
 return { Context, Provider };
}
```

i dont know how to solve this. all titles are unique as they have different numbers but still all are deleted!!!!!!!!!!!!

[here is the pic of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx2yZ.png)

Comment: What is your action.payload?

Comment: action.payload is randomly generated on context screen // return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999),
          title: `Blog Post #${state.length + 1}`,
        },